# How to specify range of time in hibernate validator engine?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, validation

I have a field which is of java.time.LocalDate type. It stores date of birth for my users...

```
@Past
@Column(nullable=false)
private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
```

I recently included hibernate validator in my maven project. I know that there is an annotation called @Past, but I see that it can take no arguments. I want the date of birth for my users to lie between 100 years to 3 years in the past.

I currently am checking this in my service class like so:

```
LocalDate dateOfBirth = account.getDateOfBirth();
    if(dateOfBirth == null) throw new SignupFormException("Date of Birth is required!", "dateOfBirth");

    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    Period age = Period.between(dateOfBirth, now);

    if(age.getYears() > 100) throw new SignupFormException("Invalid date of birth!", "dateOfBirth");
    if(age.getYears() < 3 && !age.isNegative()) throw new SignupFormException("Age too low!", "dateOfBirth");
    if(age.isNegative()) throw new SignupFormException("Invalid date of birth!", "dateOfBirth");
```

And I am catching the exception with an @ExceptionHandler spring annotation in my Controller class. But there is a LOT of code in my account validation service, so I wanted to use these tags.

Is it possible to do this using hibernate validator engine?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not use `@Past` for such case

For such validators that involve custom logic you can build your own ones : 
here a sample you can follow https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

You should also use validators from `javax.validations` since this is the standard validation library